# validation error message not changing in react native

Tags: react-native, formik, yup

I am learning how to use yup validation here is my code.
But validation error message doesn't change.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import { Formik } from "formik";

import AppTextInput from "../components/AppTextInput";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import AppButton from "../components/AppButton";
import ErrorMessage from "../components/ErrorMessage";

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().required().email("Please enter a valid email").label("Email"),
  password: Yup.string().required().min(4, "To short").label("Password"),
});

function LoginScreen() {
  return (
    <Screen style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo-red.png")} />
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, errors, setFieldTouched, touched }) => (
          <>
            <AppTextInput
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              icon="email"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("email")}
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              textContentType="emailAddress"
            />
            <ErrorMessage visible={touched.email} error={errors.email} />
            <AppTextInput
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              icon="lock"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("password")}
              secureTextEntry
              textContentType="password"
            />
            <ErrorMessage visible={touched.password} error={errors.password} />
            <AppButton onPress={handleSubmit} title="Login" />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not write the `onChangeText` prop

Write your both `AppTextInput` like this

```
<AppTextInput
   autoCapitalize="none"
   autoCorrect={false}
   onChangeText={handleChange('email')} // This was missing
   icon="email"
   keyboardType="email-address"
   onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('email')}
   name="email"
   placeholder="Email"
   textContentType="emailAddress"
/>

<AppTextInput
   autoCapitalize="none"
   autoCorrect={false}
   onChangeText={handleChange('password')} // This was missing
   icon="lock"
   name="password"
   placeholder="Password"
   onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('password')}
   secureTextEntry
   textContentType="password"
 />
```

See [Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/formik-example)

Comment: thanks a lot i was stuck here all day thankyou

Comment: @WebBuilders Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.